# How to use Google File Picker with Google Drive Java SDK based servlet to download a file selected by the user?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I use the google Filepicker to have the user select the target file and I get the file  id from the picker in the browser.  I have the user post this id to my servlet and I would like the servlet to download this file for processing.

I am struggling as how to use this java code as shown in the [sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents) . In the code samploe below , how to instantiate   Drive and File ? Please assume that the file id is already available from the Google Picker.

```
private static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file) {
        if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
          try {
            HttpResponse resp =
                service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
                    .execute();
            return resp.getContent();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            // An error occurred.
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
          }
        } else {
          // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
          return null;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Drive documentation explains how to retrieve OAuth 2.0 credentials and how to use them to instantiate a service object:

https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials

The Picker API only gives you the id of the file that has been selected. You have to send a `files.get` request to retrieve the file metadata, i.e. the File object in your snippet:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get